# Ajax rails searching issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I am searching for "cash", I get all the records on the view that is in index.html.erb alongwith my searches.

I want to view only the search results at the time of search.

For better understanding see below;

[image: screenshot.png]

I guess the problem is with my index.js.erb.

index.js.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %>

<% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %>
$('#kola').prepend("<%= j render xvaziri %>");
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>


                <a href="#" class="toggle-formed" style="float: right;" >Search</a>

                <div id="sample">

                    <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, remote: true, method: :get, class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                    <p>
                        <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", autofocus: true, class: "form-control-search" %>
                            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                        </p>
                        <% end %><br>
                    </div>



                    <%= render @xvaziris %>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr   class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= xvaziri.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

</tr>
```

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
class XvazirisController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_xvaziri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     layout "fedena"


    def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])


        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html 
        end 
    end

    def import
        Xvaziri.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to xvaziris_url, notice: "Xvaziris imported."
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new
    end

    def create
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new(xvaziri)
        if
            @xvaziri.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Created'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @xvaziri.update(xvaziri)
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Updated'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @xvaziri.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully destroyed.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def xvaziri
        params.require(:xvaziri).permit(:date, :description, :amount, :discount, :paid)
    end

end
```

xvaziri.rb

```
class Xvaziri < ActiveRecord::Base

    def to_s
        description
    end

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Xvaziri.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end


    def self.search(search)

        where (["description LIKE ? OR amount LIKE ? OR paid LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%"]) 

    end

end
```

[image: screenshot.png]

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your controller file ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the controller code.

Comment: Where is the "#kola" element? Is it a table?

Comment: Did you test your search method ? I think it's the one not returning the collection you are expecting. You should check: 1. Wether the server receive your "cash" param
2. Then check if your search method in Xvaziri returns the right collection for the right keyword.

Could you also provide your model file ?

Comment: "#kola" element is in <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">

Comment: Thanks Mr.Vincent Prigent, I put the screen-shot for the "cash" param in the terminal.Secondly, I have added the respective model for your reference.

Comment: Mr.Vincent Prigent, please have a look at the details what you asked for?

Comment: Sorry for not responding.
Did you try running your sql request directly, using a DBMS or directly looking at your returned collection in rails console ?
You should look at the collection returned by Xvaziris#search("cash")

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get this in my console;                   irb(main):005:0> Xvaziri#search("cash")
=> Xvaziri(id: integer, date: date, description: text, amount: decimal, discount: decimal, paid: dec
imal, balance: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, hidden: boolean)

Comment: I was thinking about Xvaziris.search("cash"), sorry

Comment: Thanks.Now it is showing all the records with cash in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117111/discussion-between-vincent-prigent-and-muhammad-yaseen).

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your answer.

Comment: Hi, It seems like you are upgrading fedena to rails4, What is the current status of your project ?

Comment: It is just the layout name,that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised my index.html and index.js.erb as below;

```
<% @balance = 0 %>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <a href="#" class="toggle-formed" style="float: right;" ><strong>Search</strong></a>

                <div id="sample">

                    <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, remote: true, method: :get, class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                    <p>
                        <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", autofocus: true, class: "form-control-search" %>
                            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                        </p>
                        <% end %><br>
                    </div>


                    <tbody>              
                        <%= render @xvaziris %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

index.js.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %> 
$('#kola tbody').empty(); 
<% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %> 
$('#kola tbody').append("<%= j render xvaziri %>"); 
<% end %>
```